# Finding out number of observation

Tags: statistics, self-learning

> There are $n$ scores $X_1,X_2,X_3,....,X_n$ and their sum is $80$ and sum of their squares is $400$ then which among them is the probable value of $n$
>
> A)$10$
>
> B)$9$
>
> C)$15$
>
> D)$18$

I have tried the following:

$$standard\ deviation\ \sigma=\sqrt{\frac{{\Sigma x_i^2}}{n}-(\bar{x}^2)}$$
$$=\sqrt{\frac{{\Sigma x_i^2}}{n}-(\frac{\Sigma x_i}{n})^2}$$
$$=\sqrt{\frac{400}{n}-\frac{(80)^2}{n^2}}$$
$$=\sqrt{\frac{400}{n}-\frac{6400}{n^2}}$$

But i don't know what to do further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality:

$(1^2+1^2+\ldots +1^2)(X_1^2+X_2^2+\ldots +X_n^2)\geq (1*X_1+1*X_2+\ldots +1*X_n)^2$

$n\times 400\geq 80^2$

$n\geq 16$

Therefore the only possible answer is (D).

Alternatively, you could plug in values into the expression under the square root (all values except $18$ give you negative values).